# Does a bijection exists between $U$ and $W$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following bijections:

$$Ψ:U→V$$

$$Ψ⁻¹:W→S$$

$$ξ₁:U→S$$

$$ξ₂:V→W$$

there is no known relations between $U$ and $W$ and $V$ and $S$.

My **question** is: Does a bijection exists between $U$ and $W$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES.** Let $f = \xi_2(\Psi )$. It is the bijection from $U$ to $W$.